# how to edit line with sed for installing ssl on centos

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, sed

I want to edit specific file in centos so i tried `sed` command.
This is what I'm doing:

```
SSLPATH="/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf"
sed -i 's/^SSLCertificateFile .*$/SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt/' in-$SSLPATH
sed -i 's/^SSLCertificateKeyFile .*$/SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key/' in-$SSLPATH
```

But I faced fol some errors like:

```
set -e expression ... unknown option to `s'
```

The lines I want to change are:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

Comment: Use a different delimiter.

Comment: @devnull can you give me an example...in asnwer part..thank you

Comment: Instead of `s/search/replace/` say `s|search|replace|`.